# How to speedup espresso running process in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, automated-tests, android-espresso

Everytime I try to run test cases in espresso it -

1.Builds gradle and

2.Install apk

and then starts the test case running process which takes about **3-4 minutes**.

Can I somehow make this process quicker?

Since I am not making any changes to the app code so can I simply not use the existing apk already installed on my phone for running the test cases.This could eliminate the need for installing apk each time which takes about half of the total time.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment so I am posting this as an answer.

You could try incresasing speed of gradle build process check, this [link](https://tausiq.wordpress.com/2015/02/24/android-speed-up-gradle-build-process-in-android-studio/)